# Applying alternate CSS to jQueryUI Dialog?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, themes

Is there a straightforward way to apply a whole set of CSS to a portion of a DOM tree?  For example, I have a document that uses jQuery and jQueryUI to display dialogs.  The dialog content is loaded via AJAX, so it comes in as a new / separate tree of HTML elements, which I insert into the <div> of the dialog.

What I'd like to do, essentially, is apply a different jQueryUI theme to the dialog content.  So, for example, the dialog title bar and buttons would be styled according to one theme, but the dialog content (buttons, input fields, scroll bars, text, etc.) would be styled according to a different theme.

I guess I could apply a prefix to all the classes in the dialog content, and the same prefix to the alternate CSS selectors.  Is there an easier way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jqueryui.com/download

On the right hand side, there is a list menu, within that menu is an option

```
Advanced Theme Settings
```

Drill into this, you'll get a drop down with two inputs. The first one allows you to append a 'css scope' which is actually what you want. Name it as you please.

**Also**

If you click on the question mark to the right of the input field, it will more or less describe exactly what you're saying.

`This field allows you to specify a CSS scope to limit your theme to a particular portion of a page. This is helpful when using multiple themes on a page. If you don't provide a CSS scope, your theme will apply to all UI elements on a page.`

Going on...

`In most situations, you won't need to specify a CSS scope. Please Note: If you provide a CSS scope, you will not get an example page included in your download.`

Comment: That's perfect, thanks!  (It looks to be a little fiddly to get the multiple themes to coexist in the same directory, but I have the sample page working with one theme, and when you click the "Open Dialog" button, the dialog shows up in a different theme.)

Comment: The idea is to use the class you added in the compiler as a wrapper for any elements you want to use, even if it's just an arbitrary div. Just wrap all elements you want to apply styles on in a container with the same class, and then close it so it doesn't encase other elements you don't want to have that theme applied to.